# How to change the info displayed from database based on a selection

Tags: php

I have a number of arrays structured like:

```
["data"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(45) "Account1"
        [1]=>
        string(9) "405105304"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "2712"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(46) "Account2"
        [1]=>
        string(9) "410418784"
        [2]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
```

As you can see in my example I have two accounts, for each account I take data like this:

```
 {
            $array = [];
            $path = $data->data[2]; //this is for Account1
            foreach($path as $key => $item){
                if($key > 1){ 
                    $array[] = [$item[8]];
                    $sum += $item[8];
                }
            }
            $avg = ($sum / count($array));
            return json_encode($array);
        }
```

As you can see I make an average of every 8th value. The problem is that I need to make a select button which will apply this foreach for the specific account I selected.

This is how I return the names of every account

```
      {
            $array = [];
            $path = $data->data[0];
            foreach($path as $key => $item){
                if($key > 1){ 
                    $array[] = [$item[0]];
                }
            }
            return json_encode($array);
        }
```

This is how I echo the names of the accounts in a select.

```
        <div style="margin: 5px 5px 0px; height: 30px; width: auto;">
            <div style="width: 100%; display: block;">
                <span style="display: none;">
                </span>
                <select style="width: 100%; border-radius: 5px;">
                    <option value="All" selected="selected" style=" width: auto;">All Campaigns</option>
                    <option value="405105304" style=" width: auto;"><?php echo \Helper::getCompanyNameForAdWordsAdCostPerConversion($data) ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make the data displayed change according to the account selected.

Comment: If you are not submitting the form you will need to use some js/jquery/ajax

Answer (score 1):

First you have to put for example a link with parameter to your HTML, e.g.:

```
<a href="index.php?account=3">Account 2</a>
```

Then you change your code like:

```
$path = $data->data[$_GET['account']];
```

Or you can put your select into a form and the use $_POST instead of $_GET.